# Question about delegating zone

Tags: domain-name-system, delegation

A little question about DNS. Given a domain, say:

```
example.com
```

I want to setup a subdomain like this:

```
sub.example.com
```

I want to delegate this zone to third party Name Servers(secondaries), say:

```
ns1.otherdomain.com
ns2.otherdomain.com
```

When defining the delegation within the zone file, should I specify the IP Addresses of the third party name servers, or I could just point to the FQDN of the DNS's the way I just pointed before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the servers you are delegating to are not within the sub.example.org zone all you should have to do is add a couple records like this.

```
sub             NS      ns1.otherdomain.com
sub             NS      ns1.otherdomain.com
```

If the DNS servers you where delegating to are within sub.example.org you would also need to provide [glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) records.